# Reopening feature requests with status declined

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I find interesting [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) which has [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). However, I think that such feature should be implemented and it's possible that other community members also think that. How to handle that case?

I could upvote such question, but then, it wouldn't be clear which upvotes were made before declining the feature, and which after.

I could create new question with similar feature request, but it would be probably closed as duplicate.

I could post a comment that I don't agree with that decline and hope the folks thinking the same would upvote it.

What is the etiquete for showing disagreement with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)?

Comment: When a request gets declined there may be a good reason for this. You can reask a question if there is new evidence to it. If you have that it won't get closed as duplicate and you can give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate more interest by adding a real good answer.  Then at some later point put a bounty on it.  Eventually some of these get upvoted enough that the Team thinks about them more an may implement some or all of the request, as was demonstrated by [finally allowing users to see their deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

Comment: Hmmm I think I should state clearly in that answer, that I disagree with status-declined, so that the people upvoting it vote for the team to change their mind?

Comment: Bounties on Meta are like a box of Crispy Creme donuts.  They taste good for a moment.